# How to reload ddropdown for every radiobutton on change and date textbox change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have drop down , radio-button and date textbox. when the user changes radio-button and date value the drop down get reloaded to default.

Eg: if i choose date=17-10-2015 and radiobutton = 10 and selected second option in dropdown.after i select dropdown now if i again change date or else radiobutton means the dropdown get loaded as how it is in starting.(--select--)

This should happend for every time when radiobutton changes or date changes

Comment: Please can you provide an example code?

Answer (score 0):

Next time give us more information, and you will have a greater chance to help you.
Here is some sample code how to start:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1">One
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2">Two
<input type="radio" name="test" value="3">Three

<select id="sel" name="sel"></select>

<script>
  $('input[type=radio][name=test]').on('change', function() {
      $("#sel").load("select.php?val="+$(this).val());
  });
</script>
```